# Promise.all not working as expected - Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I need promises.then () to be executed only after Promise.all is completed, however, firebase.database (), which should only be executed when the set of promises are resolved, is being executed first.

```
  const finalizarAlbum = async () => {
    setVisibleMod(false);
    if (nome && email && telefone) {
      const id = uuid();
      const promises = Promise.all(
        arrayPages.map((item, index) => {
          firebase
            .storage()
            .ref(id)
            .child(listaOrdemFotos[index])
            .putFile(item)
            .then((res) => {
              objetoPaginas.push({
                ordem: index,
                pagina: arrayPages[index],
                url: res.downloadURL,
              });

              setUnidade((unidade) => unidade + 1);
            })
            .catch((error) => setErro(erro));
        })
      );

      promises.then(() => {
        firebase
          .database()
          .ref('usuarios')
          .child(id)
          .set({
            nome,
            email,
            telefone,
            listaOrdemFotos: objetoPaginas,
          })
          .then(() => console.log('Enviado'))
          .catch((error) => setErro(erro));
      });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning anything from `.map`, so you're creating an array of `undefined`s, not an array of promises. Change it to:

```
const promises = Promise.all(
  arrayPages.map((item, index) => {
    return firebase // <---------
      .storage()
      .ref(id)
      .child(listaOrdemFotos[index])
      .putFile(item)
      .then((res) => {
        objetoPaginas.push({
          ordem: index,
          pagina: arrayPages[index],
          url: res.downloadURL,
        });

        setUnidade((unidade) => unidade + 1);
      })
      .catch((error) => setErro(erro));
  })
);
```